# Are Published messages sent to all nodes in a NATS cluster? Or only to nodes with local Subscribers to the message's Subject?

Tags: nats.io

Let's say I have a simple 2-server NATS cluster with servers A and B.

If a client on Server A publishes a message to a Subject for which there are no subscribers on Server B, does that message still get sent from Server A to Server B?

Comment: Could you please add some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the goal is here but more details could help clarify the context. If you're asking specifically whether the nodes can pass messages published on another server to a subscribed client, yes.. how long will it stay? Depending on the defined expiration time.. what if the server goes down before it shares with the mesh, almost impossible but can happen.

Also, though you're probably just illustrating, even numbers are not generally advisable in clusters to avoid split-brain situations where it's impossible to locate the truth source (seed server in this case)..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. NATS clustered servers will forward messages that it has received from a client to the immediately adjacent nats-server instances to which it has routes. Messages received from a route will only be distributed to local clients. There is not subscriber checks in the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a black and white answer because NATS supports many deployment architectures with server to client communications, server to server cluster communications, and cluster to cluster communications through gateways to form super-clusters. Gateways for example optimize the interest graph propagation (i.e. only send data to other clusters if there is interest) [Super-cluster with gateways documentation](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration/gateways#gateways)